# How do you call a full day (24 hours)

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a specific word that covers 24-hour time period between 0:00 and 23:59 on a single date?
Is there anything more specific than a "day" (which is usually opposite of night, and its primary meaning does not cover entire 24 hours, except maybe within Arctic Circle)?